# Import-Module does not work when invoking PS code from C# with PS Core 6.2.3

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, sdk

I have a PS script that has an `import-module psmod1.psm1` statement.

Inside the PS script, I do a `get-module` and then write the names of all the loaded modules to a text file.

The script runs fine when run from `pwsh` on the CLI, and I see `psmod1.psm1` written to the text file

I am invoking the script from within a .NET CORE C# application. This time the script runs fine but no module names get written to the text file (I am writing some other text to ensure the file itself is being successfully written to etc. and all that works fine).

So, since `import-module` inside the PS script did not appear to be working, I then added loading of the module to the C# code. This was done by using `InitialSessionsState.CreateDefault()` and then using `ImportPSModule`.

I still get the same results, it seems that for PS code invoked from within C# via `RunSpaceFactory.CreateRunspace`, it is impossible to import modules, either within the PS code file or from within C#. I have tested this on Windows 2008R2 as well as Windows 2012R2.

Comment: I changed the code in C# to use PowerShell.Create instead of CreatePipeline(), read the PS file into a C# string and fed it to the powershell instance via AddScript, now the import-module statement inside the PS code works fine.

I can live with this though this is a big pain as all the paths etc. are now different and I have to account for that.

I still have no idea while using PowerShell.Create from C# honors import-module inside of PS while using CreatePipeline() from C# does not honor import-module inside of PS.